# How CPU adjust the clock?

Tags: memory

I see different frequency RAMs in the market, processor runs at the specified frequency of the clock which is received from the oscillator.

Some RAMs have low specifications and some RAM have high specifications in terms of speed. How does actually the processor knows that now the RAM installed in the system is a low frequency and I have to run on the slow speed while data transferring, is it the part of hardware  or the operating system ?

When we talk about that bus runs at 33 MHz does that mean some actual clock that governs the bus operation or we just meant the time taken by the electronic signal (Bit) to reliably available on the inputs or outputs of the peripherals ?

Comment: Hint: Google "serial presence detect"

Comment: Most will use some asynchronous FIFO to communicate signals between clock domains.

Answer (score 4):

> Some RAMs have low specifications and some RAM have high specifications in terms of speed. How does actually the processor knows that now the RAM installed in the system is a low frequency and I have to run on the slow speed while data transferring, is it the part of hardware or the operating system ?

RAM bars have small nonvolatile *EEPROM* chips on there, which contain such info. It's actually standardized. The Wikipedia SDRAM article has much more info.

In any case, the memory controller subsystem in your CPU or on your Mainboard chipset (depends on the architecture) decide on this data, and often also on configuration that people are free to modify (in what is often still called "BIOS setup"), which operational characteristics to use for a RAM bar. There's much more than just bus clock – there's voltage, latencies, and a lot more; it's a fairly complex system.

> When we talk about that bus runs at 33 MHz does that mean some actual clock that governs the bus operation or we just meant the time taken by the electronic signal (Bit) to reliably available on the inputs or outputs of the peripherals ?

We mean the bus is clocked at 33 MHz.

Comment: Comments arn't really a place for further *questions*. Clarification *maybe*